# Put value in custom defined column in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create a sql query which create a column that doesn't exists in the db tables and gets fills on whether a row exists or not exists in a specific table.

For example:
I have 3 tables:
Users (For users list) - UID, UName
Locations (List of all available locations) - LID, LName
UsersLocations (All the locations the users have checked into) - UserID, LocationID
I need a sql query that from a user id get me a table of all the locations with a column that says whether the user has been in this location or not.

Example for Users table

```
UID | UName
1     John
4     Amy
5     Dann
```

Example for Locations table:

```
LID | LName
1     London
2     Barcelona
3     Paris
4     New York
```

Example for UsersLocations table:

```
UserID | LocationID
    5        1
    5        2
```

Example for output (for userid = 5):

```
User ID | Location | Was Here
5         London     true
5         Barcelona  true
5         Paris      false
5         New York   false
```

The output needs to include all the Locations from the locations table.
Also the UsersLocations table only contains the userID of the users that checked into that location.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using mysql, why is that important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm.  One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select u.userid, l.location,
       (case when exists (select 1 from userLocations where ul.userid = u.userid and ul.lid = l.locationid)
             then 'true'
             else 'false'
        end) as WasHere        
from location l cross join
     (select 5 as userid) u;
```

The only part that is database-specific is the subquery for `u`.

Comment: Well I tried this query but how can I change the user I'm searching for? for example if I wanna search just for user number 6 or 1?

I updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: ok, nvm I manged to change the query to the one I wanted. But it's awesome, it's just what I need to make that query, Thanks a lot!